# How to convert time into US time zone in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code that converts the current time into US time (GMT -4).
I am not able to find the right keyword to do so. I have the code to convert time into Europe Standard Time.
Can anyone please tell the right phrase to use in place of "W. Europe Standard Time" in Function declaration line.

------TRUNCATED CODE-----------

```
Function ConvertTime(DT As Date, Optional TZfrom As String = "Central Standard Time", _
                                 Optional TZto As String = "W. Europe Standard Time") As Date
    Dim TZones As Object
    Dim sourceTZ As Object
    Dim destTZ As Object
    Dim seconds As Single
    Dim DT_SecondsStripped As Date
    If GetOutlook Then
        'fix for ConvertTime stripping the seconds
        seconds = Second(DT) / 86400    'save the seconds as DateTime (86400 = 24*60*60)
        DT_SecondsStripped = DT - seconds
        Set TZones = oOutl.TimeZones
        Set sourceTZ = TZones.Item(TZfrom)
        Set destTZ = TZones.Item(TZto)
        ConvertTime = TZones.ConvertTime(DT_SecondsStripped, sourceTZ, destTZ) + seconds    'add the stripped seconds
    End If
End Function

Sub test_ConvertTime()
    Dim t As Date

    t = Now()
    Debug.Print t, ConvertTime(t)
'    Debug.Print t, ConvertTime(t), Format(t - ConvertTime(t), "h")
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There's no such thing as "US time" - there are multiple time zones in the US. For example, most of the time the West coast (e.g. California) is 3 hours behind the East coast (e.g. New York). Do you have a specific time zone you need to use?

Comment: Add `TZones` to the Watch window. Place a breakpoint on `Set sourceTZ = TZones.Item(TZfrom)`. Examine the `TZones` in the Watch window for keywords.

Comment: Look up the options for the `DateAdd` function...

Comment: @Dave `DateAdd` is not concerned with time zones, nor is the data type `Date` in general.

Comment: "European Central Time"? https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to use GMT -4 time zone

Comment: @RajatGupta: Regardless of whether anywhere in the world actually observes that at the time? For example, New York varies between UTC-5 and UTC-4. I'd have to check whether there *are* any time zones that are permanently UTC-4. If you actually want "the time in New York" then "Eastern Standard Time" is probably the Windows ID you want. (Don't be fooled - it still observes DST.)